Msgraph user Invite custom email template
all im trying to figure out is if its possible to make a email template for the msgraph api.
im inviting users to my azure and that sends them a email but its not a very pleasing email.
  public async sendUserInvite(body: {email: test@gmail.com}) {
    await this.client.api('/invitations').post({
      invitedUserEmailAddress: body.email,
      inviteRedirectUrl: `http://localhost:3000/`,
      sendInvitationMessage: true
    })
  }

this is the api that sends a invite email to the user.
i have searched the whole web but couldnt find anything so hope to get some answers here :P

There should the property invitedUserMessageInfo where you can setup a customized message, but I'm not sure whether the customizedMessageBody property supports only plain text or html.
public async sendUserInvite(body: {email: test@gmail.com}) {
  await this.client.api('/invitations').post({
   invitedUserEmailAddress: body.email,
   inviteRedirectUrl: `http://localhost:3000/`,
   sendInvitationMessage: true,
   invitedUserMessageInfo: {
     messageLanguage: 'en-US',
     customizedMessageBody: 'Your message'}
   })
}


i have looked further and its not possible to change the whole email template. But only having a message is also good. Thank you for your help
